# Rails 3 nested resources route error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm not being able to redirect the user to the page I want after he creates a new "service" resource.

Here's the routes.rb:

```
resources :wsps do
    resources :services
end
```

The html form:

```
<%= form_for([@wsp,@service]) do |f| %>
```

Services_controller.rb:

```
 def new
    @wsp = current_wsp
    @service = @wsp.services.build
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @service }
    end  
  end

def create
    @wsp = current_wsp
    @service = @wsp.services.build(params[:service])
    if @service.save
        redirect_to wsp_service_path
    end
  end
```

The wsp_service_path goes to /wsps/1/services and the error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"services"}
```

What am I doing wrong? Why cant't I use "wsp_service_path"?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `wsp_service_path` (while you should be use `wsp_service_url` since you are in a controller). All you are missing is arguments. `wsp_service_path` (or `_url`) are going to expect two arguments: a wsp and a service. Once you provide those two, it works.

```
redirect_to wsp_service_url(@wsp, @service)
```